# Travel around the world find the minimun point to start

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, loops

I have to find the minimum index to start two arrays like this:

```
cities= [2,4,5,2] gallons = [4,3,1,3]
```

This problem involves 2 parts

In the first part I have to find if a valid start city exist. In the above example, I can't start in the first position, due to the value in the first position of cities(cities[0]) is less than the value in the first position of gallons (gallons[0] = 4). So I have to continue looking for the correct index to start. The first point when I can start the travel is in the index 1, because cities[1] >= gallons[1]. At this point the path will be:

```
4-gallons[1] + cities[2] = 4 -3 + 5 = 6
6-gallons[2] + cities[3] = 6 -1 + 2 = 7
7-gallons[3] + cities[0] = 7 -3 + 2 = 6
6-gallons[0] = 6-4 =2
```

The return will be 1, the index where I started the journey.

The next is an invalid path so I will have to return -1 in this case:

```
cities= [8,4,1,9] gallons= [10,9,3,5]
```

In the above example I start in index 3, because it is the first position where cities is bigger than gallons, so the operations in this case will be like this:

Note: The list is circular so the next cities in this case is cities[0] =8, in the below example:

```
 9-gallons[3] + cities[2] + cities[0] = 9 -5 + 8 = 12 
12-gallons[0] + cities[1] = 12 -10 + 4 = 6
6-gallons[1] + cities[2] = 6 - 9 + 1
```

In this final operation 6-9 = -3 for this reason we don’t have enough gallons to continue the journey so the response is -1 and we don’t have to continue with the process.

The next is another case starting with index 0, because cities[0] >= gallons[0]:

```
cities[3,2,5,4] gallons = [2,3,4,2]

cities[0] - gallons [0] + cities[1] = 3-2+2 = 3
3 - gallons [1] + cities[2] = 3-3+5 = 5
5 - gallons [2] + cities[3] = 5-4+4 = 5
5 - gallons [3] = 5-2 = 3
```

The response in this case is 0 because we start in the index 0 and the route was valid, I mean we always had enough gallons to continue traveling (we didn’t have negative results between the total accumulated cities journey minus the gallons available, conversely to the example in the second case ).

The next is my code so far, but I am failing several test cases, I had done several personal test cases but I don't really know why my code is failing, any ideas? the two arrays could have different dimenssions.

```
public static int bestIndexToStartJorney(List<Integer> cities, List<Integer> gallons) {
        int n = 0;
        int starts = -1;
        int total = 0;
        if (cities.size() > 0 && gallons.size() > 0 && (cities.size() == gallons.size())) {
            n = cities.size();
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (cities.get(i) >= gallons.get(i)) {
                //Define a start point
                starts = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        //If we have a valid case.
        if (starts >= 0) {
            total = cities.get(starts);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                //Constraints
                if ((cities.get(i) < 0 || cities.get(i) > 10000) || (gallons.get(i) < 0 || gallons.get(i) > 10000)) {
                    starts = -1;
                    break;
                }
                //Define the current position to transverse circularly
                int position = (i + starts) % n;
                total += -gallons.get(position);
                //If total < gallonsance the path is invalid.
                if (total < 0) {
                    starts = -1;
                    break;
                }
                if (position < n - 1 && position + 1 != starts) {
                    total += cities.get(position + 1);
                } else {
                    if (starts > 0 && position + 1 != starts)
                        total += cities.get(0);
                }
            }
        }
        return starts;
    }
```

Constraints:

```
1<=size <= 100000
0<=cities[i] <= 10000
0<=gallons[i] <= 10000
```

Comment: do you know the failed test cases?

Comment: No, these cases are blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you use `position + 1` for the calculation of next position however that does not wrap circularly without the `% n` you used before in circular indexing position itself.

Because of this, the if else statement at the end of your for loop should be able to be replaced by the following that uses the circular indexing.

```java
int nextPosition = (position + 1) % n;
if (nextPosition != starts) {
    total += cities.get(nextPosition);
}
```

That was all I could see in the code that might be giving you issues, so without some failing test cases I cannot help you any further.

Comment: ok, Isee thanks, these cases are blocked, its hard to figure out, what  are the real issues